# Port is open and process is listening but server respond with ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port, webserver

I am forwarding external port 80 to local port 3000 that has Node.js listening and I have successfully configured DDNS in order for the client to be able to access a web app that I am currently developing. Everything was fine until today I could not externally connect to the server. But note that when I test the server with tools like https://www.yougetsignal.com with both external IP address and host name, it gives the result that the port 80 is open. But when I try to access the website from my mobile using the 4G I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I know that my router does not support hairpinning and i am accessing the website from a mobile broadband and using both hostname and external ip address but both give the same error. I have tried to reset my network setting in windows and restarted the pc but in vain. Also I have downloaded and ran a web server (https://www.rebex.net) on port 3000 to see if the problem was with NodeJs but still the port testing tool give the result that the port is open. In the ui of the later web server I am receiving the request from yougetsignal.com saying the http request was empty [figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cd5y.png) (request is recieved from yougetsignal.com and treated as an empty http request)]. Also, I tried the following commands but in vain.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset
```

Finally I disabled my firewall completely but get the same result.

What could the issue coming from? Is there any workaround or possible solution?

[UPDATE] I also installed Wireshark and I start capturing tcp packet on the wifi interface with the filter `ip.addr == 192.168.1.3 && tcp.port == 3000`. Note that ip.addr is my local ip address that i am forwarding port 80 to it in the NAT configuration, and here is the captured tcp packet on the wifi interface with the filter  note that ip.addr is my local ip address that i am forwarding port 80 to it in the NAT configuration, and here is the [capture file](https://disk.yandex.com/d/y1J9lXevwBj6pQ)

Comment: i already mentioned that the port is forwarded successfully and i am using yougetsignal.com also i set up a web server listening on port 3000 and it is logging the request from you get signal

Comment: Could you check if the port is on listening state on the Windows machine ? `netstat -an | find "LISTENING" | find "3000"`

Comment: @S.Brottes yes i tried the command and it output 
TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:3000                  [::]:0                 LISTENING